# Is there a way to pre-sort the rows in a postgresql custom aggregate without using ORDER BY in the aggregate call?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I have created a custom aggregate in pl/pgsql that requires that the rows be sorted in a certain way with respect to the input columns. I can accomplish this by using `ORDER BY` in the aggregate call. I would like this sorting to happen without explicitly stating the `ORDER BY` in the aggregate call.

E.g. I have aggregate function f(A text, B text). I can get the right calculation from it by calling it like this:

```
select
    X,
    Y,
    f(A, B order by A, B)
from
    table

group by
    X,
    Y
```

I want to be able to call it like this and specify the sorting somewhere in the custom aggregate's definition.

```
select
    X,
    Y,
    f(A, B)

from
    table

group by
    X,
    Y
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I know that in some cases you will achieve this if your data is inserted in the right order (and the rownum will help you), but as far as I know, you must use `ORDER BY` if you want to be sure the order will be respected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the aggregate to sort the input values, you may have to write the state change function so that it only collects the inputs and perform the sort in the final function. This may require lots of memory if you cache data for a large table.

Based on what your aggregate does, you may be able to come up with a better solution, but you cannot depend on a certain order of the values.